# Find the word with the greatest numbers of repeated letters

Tags: java

For this challenge I need to find the word with the greatest numbers of repeated letters. For example, if I enter `Hello world!` the output should be `Hello` as it contains `2` characters of `l`, or `No words` and it should be `-1`. 
I broke down the problem into:

1) Broke a sentence into the array of `words`

2) Went through each `word` in a loop

3) Went through each `charcater` in a loop

I'm stuck in how I should return if a word contains more letters than any other.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter any sentence or word combination: ");
    String myString = kbd.nextLine();
    String result = "";
    int count = 0;

    String[] words = myString.split("\\s+");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
            for(int k = 1; k < words[i].length(); k++) {
                char temp = words[i].charAt(k);
                if(temp == words[i].charAt(k-1)) {
                    count++;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define repeated letters? What is the repetition count of "helllo", "heelloo"?

Comment: Or perhaps `banana`? Is that value 3?

Comment: I don't understand what your k loop is doing, shouldn't you be going from k=j+1 and comparing the `.charAt(j) to .charAt(k)`? You'll also want to zero the count variable for each word, possibly for each letter(depending on how you define the count).

Comment: @BenjyKessler, it should return the word with the same first repetitive letters. In  `"heelloo"`, it should be `e` as it comes first.

Comment: @Tony, yes, correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost did it and I suppose you're looking into something like this:

```
static int mostFreqCharCount(final String word) {
    final int chars[] = new int[256];

    int max = 0;
    for (final char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        chars[c]++;
        if (chars[c] > chars[max]) // find most repetitive symbol in word
            max = c;
    }
    return chars[max];
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter any sentence or word combination: ");

    final Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String myString = kbd.nextLine();
    kbd.close();

    int maxC = 0;
    String result = "";

    final String[] words = myString.split("\\s+");
    for (final String word : words) {
        final int c = mostFreqCharCount(word);
        if (c > maxC) {
            maxC = c;
            result = word;
        }
    }

    if (maxC > 1) // any word has at least 1 symbol, so we should return only 2+
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

the main idea - calculate number of most frequent symbol for each word and store only maximal one in variables `maxC` and `result`

Comment: nice! use a 256 array instead of a HashMap, much cleaner

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yep, for full set of java symbols you need to use 65536-length array

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an array of length = words.length, and store the highest value for each word in its relative index:

```
int counts[] = new int[words.length];
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++){
            count = 0
            for(int k = k+1; k < words[i].length(); k++){
                if(words[i].charAt(j) == words[i].charAt(k)){
                    count++;
                }
            if(counts[i] < count)
                  counts[i] = count;
      }

}
```

Then just scan through the array for the highest value, n, and return words[n]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the ONE word with the greatest count, you only need three variables, one for currentBestWord, one for currentLargestCount, and one to keep the count of characters in a word.

```
int currentLargestCount=0;
String currentBestWord="";
HashMap<String,Integer> characterCount=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
String[] words=myString.split("\\s+");
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    String w=words[i];
    characterCount=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(int j=0;j<w.length();j++){
        String character=w.charAt(j).toString();
        if(characterCount.containsKey(character)){
            characterCount.put(character,characterCount.get(character)+1);
        }else{
             characterCount.put(character,1);
        }
    }
    // Now get the largest count of this word
    Iterator ir=characterCount.ValueSet().iterator();
    int thiscount=0;
    while(ir.hasNext()){
         int thischaractercount=ir.next();
         if(thiscount<thischaractercount) thiscount=thischaractercount;
    }
    if(thiscount>currentLargestCount){
        currentLargestCount=thiscount;
        currentBestWord=w;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better change to `Map<Character, Integer>`