# Find the greatest number of repeated letter in a word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regex to find the **greatest** number of repeated letter in a word in **JavaScript**?
 The repeated letter could be separated with other letters like "memo":'m' being separated with 'e'.
For example: the word "greatest" should return 2 cause either 'e' or 't' repeated two times and two is maximum repeated times. 
I've tried pattern like `/([a-z]{1,})\1/` but it's not working with this case.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: so in your example is 2 returned because the maximum is 2, or because 2 letters share the maximum? ... in other words, should memo return 1 or 2 ... and, I doubt regex can do what you want in either case

Comment: @JaromandaX 'memo' should return 2. Just return the maximum, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Why do you need regular expressions for this? They are not normally used to count things.

Comment: [Now you have two problems.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/223634/66652)

Comment: @samsonthehero Yeah you'r e right. But how can I match this case by using Regular expressions? Just curious..

Comment: @AndyHu It's not possible with just regular expressions.

Comment: why do you insist on using Regex? How can I use a chainsaw to fix a flat tyre?

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I know I chose a wrong way...

Comment: Regular languages are context free. What you're trying to accomplish requires context. There may be some convoluted way to use them for this case (though I don't think there is), but that is only because regex implementers have jammed as many advanced features as possible into them.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246883/find-the-word-with-the-greatest-numbers-of-repeated-letters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579568/most-repeating-character-in-a-string, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142700/get-count-of-most-repeated-letter-in-a-word.

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes, regular languages are context free, but back references do provide bits of state and context-awareness.

Comment: @torazaburo I know. That's why I said that his question requiring context *might* have been possible with advanced features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the javascript way of accomplishing this. Doing this with regular expressions is not possible.

```
var exp = 'hello world' ;
var expCounts = {};
var maxKey = '';
for(var i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
    var key = exp[i];
    if(!expCounts[key]){
     expCounts[key] = 0;
    }
    expCounts[key]++;
    if(maxKey == '' || expCounts[key] > expCounts[maxKey]){
        maxKey = key;
    }
}

console.log(maxKey + ":" + expCounts[maxKey]);    //logs l:3
```

---

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/v72qa872/

Answer (score 3):

> How can I use regex to find the greatest number of repeated letter in a word in JavaScript?

You cannot, unless you are willing to restrict the maximum number of repetitions, in which case you can do it with the following:

```
regexp = /(?:.*(.)(?:.*\1){2})|(?:.*(.)(?:.*\2){1})/
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          MATCH 2 REPETITIONS  MATCH ONE REPETITION
```

This is for the case of a maximum of two repetitions (three occurrences of the same character). What this does is find the first match for a sequence of a particular character (`(.)`), followed by anything and that character again (`.*\1`), repeated twice; in other words, the character occurs three times. If that does not match, then it finds the first match for a sequence of a particular character followed by anything and that character again, repeated once; in other words, the character occurs twice. You can extend this up to your preferred maximum number of allowed repetitions (9, since AFAIK back references only support single digits).

If you use this as in

```
match = 'aabbbcc'.match(regexp)
```

then the correct answer (`"b"`) will be in `match[1]`. If there are no repetitions, the call to `match` will fail.

Comment: ...unless you have a "regex" engine like .NET's that can count repeated captures... `(.)(?=(?:.*?(\1))+)`, together with `.Matches()` would return a list of matches, each containing a list of captures; you'd just have to find the longest one. OK, that's an extra step needed outside of the regex engine, but pretty close. At any rate, regex definitely isn't the right tool for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do this with JavaScript:

```js
function greatestRepeat(str) {
    var maxRepeat = 0;
    var letterRepeated = null;
    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
     var currentLetter = str.charAt(i);
        var timesRepeated = str.split(currentLetter).length-1;
        if(timesRepeated > maxRepeat) {
            maxRepeat = timesRepeated;
            letterRepeated = currentLetter;
        }
    }
    return letterRepeated;
}
console.log(greatestRepeat("memo"));
```

As I mentioned in the comments, this cannot be done purely with regular expressions. As *@MillieSmith* stated this is because regular languages are context free.

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, `greatestRepeat("aabbbcc")` returns `a`, not `b`. I'm not quite sure what the line with `split` in it is trying to do?

Comment: @torazaburo Fixed, the line with `split` gets the current number of repeats for that character. I accidentally changed it from `str` to `currentLetter` in an edit and didn't notice.